# How to find bash script name from pid?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm using SUNOS. First I run that command to find top cpu using proccesses.

```
ps -eo pmem,pcpu,pid,args | sort -rnk 2
```

Then its the output

```
0.0  4.2 19105 bash
```

19105 is 'process id' and, 'bash' is args.

I just saw **bash** in args section. How can I find which bash script is working? I tried **pwdx** command but it just shows me working directory of script. It doesnt show me that which script is working with this pid.

I wish someone help me.

Comment: Operating system is SUNOS

Comment: Looks like it's reading from somewhere else instead of executing code in a file.

Comment: Try looking around `/proc/19105/fd/0`.

Comment: @iBug i found the file. it has no rwx privilege i tried to change this with chmod but operating system dont let me do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `PID` of any process, you can use `ps -ef|grep pid` to check the running process and its parent-pid (column 3).

If you want to know more, check `ps- ef|grep parent-pid` to find from where the child process is spawned.

You can use this to even find the user/terminal who has executed the process.

Comment: its PPID=1 :(  :( @Lohit Gupta

Comment: Looks like its either an orphan process or one of the startup OS processes, coz most of the time those have a `PPID` of 1